# Error al enviar correos mediante un package de SSIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, ssis

tengo una duda, quiero crear una tarea de enviar correo a traves de SSIS, configure lo basico que me requiere Visual Studio, pero al ejecutar la tarea me lanza este error.

```
[send mail task] error: an error occurred with the following error message: "se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación.".
```

Y tengo esta configuración:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no pongas imágenes de no ser necesario. puedes poner el código de tu implementación? ahí sólo dice que se excedió el tiempo de espera, puede que a donde quieres mandarlo o tu servidor no funcione correctamente

Comment: pues en si, solo tengo eso de información amigo, no tengo aun algo codificado para el envío de correos, todo hasta ahorita lo tengo en una sola tarea